# How to download file revision [without checking out directory]

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, solaris

**TortoiseSVN** (on Windows) has the option to download a **file** revision to your computer without having to checkout/update a working copy.  You just select the revision you want to download and where.  See ***"Save Revision to..."*** option from the ***"Show Log"*** window.

I need to do this, but using command-line Subversion, on Solaris.

I found that using `svn cat -r ### path/file.sh > /new_path/file.sh` seems to work, but I don't know if it is the "proper" way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn export` is what you want. And applicable for both files and directories:

```
svn export -r 100 url/path/file.sh /new_path/file.sh
```

Comment: Great!  From what I had read, you could only export directories.